# A question to ask about birth rank or serial number

Tags: grammar, adjectives

*Are you the third of your parents' children? or the second issue?*

Or, *you are the third guy, eh?*

What is the question for which *"he came third in the race"* is an answer?.

Instead of resorting to such a questioning is there a single  word to interrogatively  seek information of placement on a  time marker line ?

All Indian languages have such a word, none in English afaik..

Comment: This is the Howmanyeth question and it's one of the most asked questions. "In what place did he come in?" would be the verbal question. I'm putting it as a comment because this question has been asked and answered.

Comment: Indeed, this has been asked, and answered, [over 40 times](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/13662?lq=1) before. In fact it's in our [top 15 questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent) ever asked. That's another good place to start, apart from the site search.